# Subsite manage Alerts permissions issue

Tags: permissions

I added a new user to a Sharepoint site, with Contribute permissions.

I also added them to a subsite, with Contribute permissions.

However they can't Manage/Create alerts on the subsite, but from what I can tell, other users with a similar setting can do so without a problem.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Contribute permissions allows users to create alerts but not manage them.  Double check the permissions role by going to Site Actions, Advanced Permissions.  Click on the Settings, Permissions levels and click on the Contribute permissions to see if Create Alerts might have been removed.

By default, the only ones who can manage alerts are those with Full Control permissions.